# What is the difference between filter2D, and Conv2D?

Tags: python, opencv, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

When I have to sharpen an image using opencv, I use:

```
#Create our shapening kernel    
kernel_sharpening = np.array([[0,-1,0], 
                              [-1, 5,-1],
                              [0,-1,0]])

# applying the sharpening kernel to the input image & displaying it.
sharpened = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel_sharpening)
```

In above code sharpened is our resultant image. As you can see in above code I used opencv function named filter2D to perform convolution of input image with the kernel, and as a result I got sharpened image.

Recently I went through this link regarding image Super-Resolution ([link](https://hub.packtpub.com/using-srgans-to-generate-photo-realistic-images-tutorial/))

And found out Keras has something similar to filter2D and Keras calls it  Conv2D.

Its syntax is as follows:

```
dis2 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same')(dis1)
```

My question is what is the difference between opencv filter2D, and Keras Conv2D ?

(I assume both do the same role of convolution of image with a kernel, I may be wrong pls correct)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question, but with OpenCV, you can only run a *constant* pre-defined filter. but with Keras, you can learn the weights particular to your problem and dataset!

Comment: Could you show how "sharpened" image (described in above code) can be generated using Conv2D using code. That will solve my query.

Comment: One could do that using the `.set_weights` functionality and set the weight to a particular filter matrix, but I'd say that is not what the keras is built for. It is built for use-cases where you'd be learning the filter values and not using constant values to do convolutions.

Comment: Absence of code does not solve my query. I would really appreciate if you make a short code snippet to sharpen an image using Conv2D, and explain the difference it has over filter2D